# Matplotlib: How to get the inverse function of a colormap?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap, inverse

In matplotlib colormaps are functions that map numbers between 0 and 1 to a 4-tuple that represents the R, G, B and A components of a color. If I have such a colormap, say `plt.cm.jet`, is there a way to get the inverse of that function, that is a function that maps the 4-tuple back to the original number between 0 and 1?

**Example:**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

values = np.random.rand(10, 10)  # could be any array
colors = plt.cm.jet(values)
values2 = # ... somehow compute values from colors here
assert values == values2
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the mapping is bijective, you could create a dict where the colors are the keys

```
reversemap={}
for color,value in zip(colors,values):
    reversemap[color] = value
```

Unfortunately, there are several colormaps that are not bijective and in those cases, inverting the mapping would be ill posed.

Comment: Thank you, that would work for the specific example I gave in the question. But I'm looking for a more general inverse function that I can use on any `colors` array.

Comment: @Fränki Do you have a forward mapping between colors and values in hand?  If so, you can always generate the reverse mapping as described.

Comment: @John the reverse mapping might not be unique

Comment: @Jonas assuming the forward mapping is bijective (and I'm struggling to think of a case where it wouldn't be) the reverse mapping will be unique.

Comment: @John for example the colormaps "flag", "prism" or "hsv" are not bijective

Comment: @Jonas  Interesting.  I suppose in those cases, the answer to the question would have to be "no, it's not possible"